# best alternative to Mutex--- which takes lesser execution time

Tags: c, pthreads

See the following code:

I am having some library file like libexample.so
And in my code i am using some function X(inputbuffer , outputbuffer)present in library

```
/*
Assume for each thread there are corresponding input buffers and output buffers
example if there are 50 threads 50 input buffers and out buffers are available
i.e input buffers are unique to each other so as output buffers....
*/
void* threadFunX(void *num)
{
    Mutex lock();
    int ret = X(inputBuffer,outputbuffer,length);
    if(ret)
    {
        //store the output buffer in afile
    }
    else
        error occured.....
    Mutex unlock();
    pthread_exit(NULL);
}

int main()
{
    pthread_t thread1[100];

    for(i=0;i<100;i++){
        p1 = pthread_create(&thread1[i],NULL,threadFunX,(void *)i);
        if(p1)
            printf("Error occurred while creating thread.....\n");
        //pthread_join( thread1[i], NULL);
    }
    for(i=0;i<100;i++)
        pthread_join( thread1[i], NULL);

}
```

My question:
If we are not using Mutex we are getting output buffer corrupted.... for this reason we are using mutex....
Is there any alternative method other than mutex....
I want to use this library function efficiently.....
My main moto is I want to reduce running time taken by mutex method also...
for example...if my code with mutex is running with 0.2 seconds..... I want better alternative method which takes lesser time than mutex with thread parallel programming...

Thanks in advance...

Comment: Is `Mutex un/lock();` pseudeo code for calls on a `pthread_mutex_t` object?

Comment: istheresomesortofrecentdiseaseepidemicthatispreventingproperindentation?

Comment: @alk... Mutex un/lock is pseudeo code...

Comment: at least in your example: creating 100 threads with the whole code being mutexed dosn't make too much sense,

Answer (score 0):

Check the library function **X**. Are you sure it is creating a new **OutputBuffer** everytime you are calling the function. Because as per your saying that "without mutex outputbuffer is getting corrupted", it seems to me that only one outputbuffer is created and it is returning the same to each thread.